# Why are my associated entities null after saving?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an entity with a 1-to-1 relationship with another entity. They are appropriately connected in my entity model and the underlying tables are related by FK.

When I called `.SaveChanges()` my entity is saved. I can see that ID which has been generated and all the corresponding values.

I can also view the database manually and see that it has been saved correct.

However, the related entities are all null in my code. They show up null in the context menu and they resolve to null in code... If I call my get method using the new Id, I get the entity I expect, again with null related entities.

If I refresh the page (or re-construct the class) then everything is correct.

**EDIT:** More details.

In my specific case I have what amounts to a join-table, creating a dependency relationship between things.

Consider a table called "Things" with a column "ThingId"

Then I have another table called "ThingDependencies" with three columns "DependencyId", "FromThingId" and "ToThingId", both of which FK to `Things.ThingId`

I have asserted in code that this data is acyclical.

When I save a new `ThingDependency` it displays the persisted values appropriately... that is: it has it's Id, and the From and To Id values.

...**but the associated entities are null** and I can't access them until I dispose the data context and re-instantiate it... then it works just fine.

Comment: Is there any chance your entity is "detached"? This can happen if your data context gets disposed before you are done working with a particular entity.

Comment: @DanM not in this case. I can call the explicit "get" for the entity and it still returns with the null values. If I explicitly dispose the context and then re-instantiate it then the properties are populated.

Comment: You probably know this already, but another thought. If you are using Code First, have you made `Dependency`, `ToThing`, and `FromThing` virtual? I believe this is used by the proxy version of your entity to on-demand fill any data in your entity that is not "raw".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I save a new ThingDependency it displays the persisted values
>   appropriately... that is: it has it's Id, and the From and To Id
>   values.
>
> ...but the associated entities are null and I can't access them until
>   I dispose the data context and re-instantiate it... then it works just
>   fine.

I can only refer to this part of your question which *sounds like* (but I may be totally wrong with my interpretation) that you are doing something like this:

```
int newThingDependencyId = 0;

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    ThingDependency newThingDependency = new ThingDependency();
    newThingDependency.FromThingId = 1;
    newThingDependency.ToThingId = 2;

    context.ThingDependencies.Add(newThingDependency);

    context.SaveChanges();

    newThingDependencyId = newThingDependency.Id;

    Thing fromThing1 = newThingDependency.FromThing;
    Thing toThing1 = newThingDependency.ToThing;
}

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    ThingDependency newThingDependency = context.ThingDependencies
        .Find(newThingDependencyId);

    Thing fromThing2 = newThingDependency.FromThing;
    Thing toThing2 = newThingDependency.ToThing;
}
```

And here you are wondering why `fromThing1` and `toThing1` are `null` but `fromThing2` and `toThing2` are not `null`, right?

If yes, then you have to replace ...

```
ThingDependency newThingDependency = new ThingDependency();
```

...by...

```
ThingDependency newThingDependency = context.ThingDependencies.Create();
```

`Create` will create a dynamic proxy that is able to load `fromThing1` and `toThing1` by lazy loading while an ordinary object created with the `new` operator is not. `Find` (or any LINQ query like `Single`, etc.) will also instantiate a proxy which is the reason why accessing the navigation properties in the second context works. All that under the assumption that your navigation properties are marked as `virtual` and you didn't disable lazy loading explicitly.

(If I'm totally wrong with this *please for the love of all `Thing`s* provide some code snippets in your question to show what you are doing exactly!)

Answer (score 0):

Provalvemnete you are with Lazy Loading off.
Try using "Include (" Entity ") in your query.

var employees = db.Employees. Include (x => x.Address). ToList ();

Att

Julio Spader

[wessolucoes.com.br](http://wessolucoes.com.br)

Comment: Lazy loading on or off would not cause this problem. Just to check anyway I tried it both ways.